# bash redirect output of command to file appended with space separator

Tags: bash, loops

I'm running a large loop that calls a program that outputs a single value. I would like to redirect that output to a text file appended by a space rather than a new line. Is there any way to do this?

```
for i in {1..1000000000}; do
    mincstats file${i}.mnc -mean -quiet >> output.txt
done
```

I have tried assigning the output to a variable as below, but I think this may be taking up unnecessary processing time. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

```
for i in {1..1000000000}; do
    var=$(mincstats file${i}.mnc -mean -quiet)
    echo -n $var >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: `echo` is a built-in; it's not going to use any significant amount of time over what `mincstats` already requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could translate all the newlines to space.

It's also more efficient to do the redirection on the whole loop, instead of each command.

```
for i in {1..1000000000}; do
    mincstats file${i}.mnc -mean -quiet
done | tr '\n' ' ' >> output.txt
```

Comment: yep think this is the best way.

Comment: Thanks! both suggestions work, but this seems to run a little bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for ((i=1;i<=1000000000;i++)); do 
  echo -n "$(mincstats file${i}.mnc -mean -quiet) "
done > output.txt
```

Comment: You'll echo a newline after the space.